# How do I import custom ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, google-closure-compiler

I have one JavaScript file at `http://localhost:8000/static/home/js/edit_sites.js`, which is trying to access a module at `localhost:8000/static/global/js/modules/reorder.mjs`.

*edit_sites.js*

```js
import { reorder } from '/static/global/js/modules/reorder.mjs';

$(() => {
  reorder($('.screenshot-list'));
});
```

*reorder.mjs*

```js
export const reorder = ($ul) => {
  // reorder screenshots by clicking arrows
  const $up = $ul.find('.controls :first-child');
  const $down = $ul.find('.controls :last-child');
  const paddingBottom = 8;

  $up.on('click', function () {
    const $li = $(this).parents('li');

    if (!$li.is(':first-child')) {
      const $prev = $li.prev();

      $li.animate(
        { bottom: `${$prev.outerHeight() + paddingBottom}px` },
        500,
        function () {
          $(this).after($prev.detach()).prop('style', '');
        },
      );

      $prev.animate(
        { top: `${$li.outerHeight() + paddingBottom}px` },
        500,
        function () {
          $(this).prop('style', '');
        },
      );
    }
  });

  $down.on('click', () => {
    const $li = $(this).parents('li');

    if (!$li.is(':last-child')) {
      const $next = $li.next();

      $li.animate(
        { top: `${$next.outerHeight() + paddingBottom}px` },
        500,
        function () {
          $(this).before($next.detach()).prop('style', '');
        },
      );

      $next.animate(
        { bottom: `${$li.outerHeight() + paddingBottom}px` },
        500,
        function () {
          $(this).prop('style', '');
        },
      );
    }
  });

  // update value of hidden order field on submit
  $('form').on('submit', function () {
    let order = '[';

    $ul.children('li').each(function () {
      order += `${$(this).data('id')}`;

      if (!$(this).is(':last-child')) {
        order += ', ';
      }
    });

    order += ']';

    $('input[name="order"]').val(order);

    return true;
  });
};
```

However, when I try to minify it using Closure, I get this error message:

```
java -jar bin/closure-compiler-v20200504.jar --language_in=STABLE --js home/static/home/js/edit_sites.js --js_output_file home/static/home/js/edit_sites.min.js
home/static/home/js/edit_sites.js:1: ERROR - [JSC_JS_MODULE_LOAD_WARNING] Failed to load module "/static/global/js/modules/reorder.mjs"
import { reorder } from '/static/global/js/modules/reorder.mjs';
^

1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

I wonder how I should define the path, as several attempts to do so did not work. Some paths (of many) I've tried:

```js
import { reorder } from './home/static/global/js/modules/reorder.mjs';
import { reorder } from './static/global/js/modules/reorder.mjs';
import { reorder } from '/home/matt/Repositories/project-dir/home/static/global/js/modules/reorder.mjs';
```

I think part of the problem is that Closure is trying to access the module from a different location than the script is. I'm new to writing modules, so I'm not entirely sure where the `.` directory even is. Closure executes in `/home/matt/Repositories/project-dir`, but when I stem my path from there, I get an error. Here's my static directory structure with irrelevant files omitted, in case you'd like to step through visually:

```
arch-laptop static > tree (pwd)
/home/matt/Repositories/project-dir/home/static
├── global
│   ├── img
│   ├── js
│   │   └── modules
│   │       └── reorder.mjs
│   └── sass
├── home
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
│   ├── js
│   │   └── edit_sites.js
│   └── sass
└── lib
    ├── css
    └── js

13 directories, 55 files
```

## Edit

I should have made it clear in my original post that my ultimate goals are:

1. Minifying these two files, and
2. Using them without error.

Despite receiving useful information here, I am still stuck on step one. I have been able to minify the ES6 module, `reorder.mjs` → `reorder.min.mjs`, but not the regular ES6 file, `edit_sites.js`.

I found a Closure compile option that might be useful:

```
java -jar ./bin/closure-compiler-v20201102.jar --help | less -R
…
JS Modules:
 --js_module_root VAL                   : Path prefixes to be removed from ES6
                                          & CommonJS modules.
…
```

…so I update line 1 of `edit_sites.js` to include the path to the newly created `reorder.min.mjs` file, relative to `edit_sites.js` (as the two answers below suggested):

```js
import { reorder } from '../../global/mjs/modules/reorder.min.mjs';
```

…but when I try compiling, I get the same error as before:

```
java -jar bin/closure-compiler-v20201102.jar --js_module_root ../../global/mjs/modules --js home/static/home/js/edit_sites.js --js_output_file home/static/home/js/edit_sites.min.js
home/static/home/js/edit_sites.js:2:0: ERROR - [JSC_JS_MODULE_LOAD_WARNING] Failed to load module "../../global/mjs/modules/reorder.min.mjs"
  2| import { reorder } from '../../global/mjs/modules/reorder.min.mjs';
     ^

1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

I've wondered if:

1. I should be using an `import` statement in a regular JS file at all. For example, I've tried removing the import from `edit_sites.js`, minifying it without error, and importing with the following HTML:

```html
<script type="module" src="/static/global/mjs/reorder.min.mjs"></script>
<script src="/static/home/js/edit_sites.min.js"></script>
```

However, I get this error in the console:

```js
11:23:23.859 Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable reorder
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8000/static/global/mjs/reorder.min.mjs:8
reorder.min.mjs:8:69
```

2. I should be using a path relative to `closure-compiler-v20200504.jar` with the `--js_module_root` flag. However, changing line 1 to

```js
import { reorder } from '../home/static/global/mjs/modules/reorder.min.mjs';
```

doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 3):

I would use '../' to step back a few folders and then '/:name' to step forward.

Try:
Import { reorder } from '../../global/js/modules/reorder.mjs';

Also if your text editor has intellisense it should suggest folders to you after you type '/'. I recommend using vscode or sublime for a project like this.

Comment: I'm using VS Code, and IntelliSense has helped me to build the path `../../global/js/modules/`, but I can't select the file. It appears in the sidebar, but not the context menu. Could this be related to why Closure can't find it? Also, I tried `touch`ing the file, but that didn't help.

Comment: You can only select the file with IntelliSense if it is a .js file. Your file is a .mjs file which means that you will have to type reorder.mjs yourself after you have determined the folder path. I just modeled your project in VS Code and I had no problem importing reorder.mjs.

The file path that I used was ```import {reorder} from '../../global/js/modules/reorder.mjs';```

Comment: I've added more to the question. Please take a look and see if there's anything you or I haven't tried.

Answer (score 1):

The closure are looking for the module file, so the path is incorrect;

try to put `../../static/global/js/modules/reoder.mjs` or even `../../global/js/modules/reoder.mjs` one of those can handle this :)

Comment: Those didn't work, and I was aware of the typo. `reoder` → `reorder`